# Can we use Windows 7 to develop VB 6.0 applications ? Is it supported officially?

Tags: windows-7, vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has anyone had success with Visual Studio 6 on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339536/has-anyone-had-success-with-visual-studio-6-on-windows-7)
>   [Installation of VB6 on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495680/installation-of-vb6-on-windows-7)

Can we develop VB6.0 applications in Windows? Is it supported by Microsoft? If supported please give the support agreement link from Microsoft?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installation of VB6 on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495680/installation-of-vb6-on-windows-7) and [Does the VB6 IDE run on Windows 7 64-bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-64-bit) and [Win 7 good VB6 development environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106555/win-7-good-vb6-development-environment?lq=1)

Comment: Oh and the VB6 IDE is not supported by Microsoft at all any more.

Comment: I know there are steps to make VB6 to work on Windows7, I want to know whether its officially supported by Microsoft or not?

Comment: As I said, the IDE is not officially supported anywhere any more. For support for the VB6 runtime, See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/447007/588306).

Comment: @Deanna: Ok thanks. Sorry again.. IDE not supported means , we shouldnot develop VB6.0 applications in Windows 7 and its not officially supported right?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but there is no support from Microsoft for VB6 development at all. Have you read the linked questions and the associated support statement from Microsoft yet? They give the definitive answer.

Comment: Yes I read it.Thanks for the links..

Comment: @MarkJ Yeah I left that one out of the list of duplicates I gave as it was aimed more at VS6, even if most answers were for VB6 :)

Answer (score 3):

I will repeat the excellent comments in answer format:

**VB6 IDE**

- You can [use the VB6 IDE on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339536/has-anyone-had-success-with-visual-studio-6-on-windows-7) (even [64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501061/does-the-vb6-ide-run-on-windows-7-64-bit)).

  - But the IDE [is not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx) at all, on Windows 7 or anywhere else. If you do have problems with the IDE, Microsoft will not help you.

**VB6 Runtime**

- The VB6 runtime is supported on all current versions of Windows [including 7 and 8, 32-bit and 64-bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx). If you have problems running a program built with VB6, you can [ask Microsoft for help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb266240.aspx). There may be a fee.

Comment: Thanks for your concise answer.